# Downloading multiple files using Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, download

I have a few seperate fields in my database that stores the file name & path of various kind of files (codes, guides, images, video)
 - E.g. ImageName,ImagePath,VideoName,VideoPath,etc

I decided to bind the file names in a single column. This is how I display them in my gridivew.

[image]

When I click the download link, there is an exception.
An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Could not find a part of the path

This are my codes when the user clicks the Download link :

```
  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.CommandName == "download")
      {
          int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
          GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
          string fName = row.Cells[1].Text;

          Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";               

          Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fName);
          //Retrieve the file
          Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("SFiles/Submissions/" + Session["userid"] 
          + "/" + fName));
          Response.End();
        }
 }
```

I believe this exception is thrown due to the fact that I bind multiple data fields in a single column and therefore, there are more than one filepath. I'm still not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

fname in your case will be equal to "mycodes.zip instalationguide.zip etc"

and therefore the following comand will fail

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fName);

First of all: this is not good practice. a malicious can probably download most of the files on your hard drive by injecting bad data in the post.

Second: you will have problems downloading multiple files in one request, the solution would be to zip(or someting simular) them serverside and then send the ziped file to the user.

Comment: Yeah there's a security risk there. You want to be passing down the ID of the record then doing a look up on the for the files to send.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send multiple files down as you can only send one file or one page per response.

Any sites that allow you to download multiple files will take the files you've selected, zip them and have you download the zip file.

Of course what you could do is have the code open several tabs/windows and have each one download it's respective file but that would be horrible, messy, unintuitive and... did I mention horrible? Plus you could run into problems with security software blocking multiple tabs/windows so stop thinking about it.